Why must I add a "then" after "finally" in order to chain promises?
Per this fiddle, if I try to call a second promise function from the .finally() block of the first promise, the second promise resolves but the resolve value is "undefined".
However, if I call the second promise function in a .then block after the .finally block, everything works as expected.  Why can't I call the second promise in the .finally block of the first promise?
Example that fails (Promise 2 value is "undefined"): https://jsfiddle.net/scemohkb/
function res(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(v); }) }
function rej(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(v); }) }

rej(1)
.then((val) => {
    console.log(`Value1: ${val}`);
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.error(`Caught 1: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 1");
    return res(2);
})
.then((v) => {
    console.log(`Value2: ${v}`); // THIS DOESN'T WORK: v is undefined
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(`Caught 2: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 2");
});

Example that works: (Promise 2 returns the correct value):  https://jsfiddle.net/scemohkb/1/
function res(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(v); }) }
function rej(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(v); }) }

rej(1)
.then((val) => {
    console.log(`Value1: ${val}`);
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.error(`Caught 1: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 1");
})
.then(() => {
    return res(2);
})
.then((v) => {
    console.log(`Value2: ${v}`); // This works: v is the correct value.
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(`Caught 2: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 2");
});

In example 1, the second promise function still returns correctly upon calling resolve() and the .then block is executed, but the value sent to resolve() is ignored and instead the .then() function receives "undefined".
What is different about the .finally() function that I'm missing, that prevents this from happening? It would seem to make sense for the cleanest chaining of multiple promises that can resolve or reject independently, vs. adding another .then() function after the .finally().

So many issues here: your res and rej functions are superfluous there are already static methods on the Promise constructor that do that, you don't need to wrap your return values in your .then handlers in a Promise, .then always wraps the return value in a Promise. As for your question per mdn, .finally will resolve/reject with the state of the state of the current Promise.

@JaredSmith please assist me in understanding the correct way to chain promises without having a stack of nested .finally() functions.  Thanks

...but I can't tell what you're trying to do: you have code that has a bunch of errors and misconceptions and other than saying .finally needs to go at the tail end of the Promise chain (it's literally in the name) and that the return value is ignored I'm not sure what of your question remains?

@JaredSmith I am simply trying to execute multiple Promise-based functions sequentially, regardless of whether the previous function succeeded or failed.

I would say then that your code is ok except you can't return a value from .finally. Your code works as written if you add return 2; inside the first .catch block.

@jared smith So, let's say I have 10 sequential Promise-based functions to call.  I want each one to be run, then regardless of the result, the next one should be run after either success or fail.  So far, I'm seeing that adding a .then() after each .finally() lets me chain them all together.  Is there anything wrong with this paradigm?

Response was too long for a comment, I just added an answer. If that isn't clear enough please comment on it and we can continue down there where we have more space to work with.

Too long to continue in the comments, so I'm posting this as an answer:

Let's say I have 10 sequential Promise-based functions to call. I want each one to be run, then regardless of the result, the next one should be run after either success or fail. So far, I'm seeing that adding a .then() after each .finally() lets me chain them all together. Is there anything wrong with this paradigm?

Yes. You don't need .finally.
Promise.prototype.finally is not meant to be a "keep this chain going regardless of whether or not the previous Promise resolved or rejected". It can't, it doesn't have access to the state of the preceding Promise. The callback you pass it does not take parameters, and its return value is ignored. That actually makes sense if you think about it in terms of try/catch/finally: the code in the finally block does not have access to the variables scoped to the try and catch blocks.
What .finally is actually meant for is use cases like cleaning up resources that need to be freed regardless of outcome like closing file handles and web socket subscriptions. It's only useful at the tail end of the chain for cleanup, which is why it's called "finally".
That still leaves the question of how to do what you're after here, which is simple if tedious: have .catch handlers that return a meaningful value so that the computation can proceed. Something like this:
const a = async (n = 0) => {
    if (Math.round(Math.random())) {
        throw new Error('oops');
    }

    return 5 + n;
};

const handleError = (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    return 0;
} 

Promise.resolve(7)
  .then(a)
  .catch(handleError)
  .then(a)
  .catch(handleError)
  .then(a)
  .catch(handleError)
  .then(console.log);

Now IRL you probably won't be calling the same function and using the same error handler over and over again: you might be able to abstract out some bits but you'll likely need to write bespoke callbacks at each step of the chain. Still this can hopefully serve as an illustration of how this works.
Playground

Directly copy pasting from the docs:
A finally() call is usually transparent and does not change the eventual state of the original promise. So for example:
Unlike Promise.resolve(2).then(() => 77, () => {}), which returns a promise eventually fulfilled with the value 77, Promise.resolve(2).finally(() => 77) returns a promise eventually fulfilled with the value 2.
Similarly, unlike Promise.reject(3).then(() => {}, () => 88), which returns a promise eventually fulfilled with the value 88, Promise.reject(3).finally(() => 88) returns a promise eventually rejected with the reason 3.
The only exception to the above rule is when finally() itself rejects (by throwing a value).

.finally() resolves with the value that the .then() and .catch() resolve with. The main reason this does not work is there is no return from inside the handlers of  from then() and catch() and hence no resolution/rejection. That is why finally() also does not resolve/reject with any value.
If you return a value from inside the handlers of then() and catch(), then the handler of finally() can resolve/reject with that value.


function res(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(v); }) }
function rej(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(v); }) }

rej(1)
.then((val) => {
    console.log(`Value1: ${val}`);
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.error(`Caught 1: ${e}`);
    return e;
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 1");
    //return res(2); //This is useless, and no matter what is put here will have no effect
    throw (5); //This is the only exception that can work
})
.then((v) => {
    console.log(`Value2: ${v}`);
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(`Caught 2: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 2");
});



Uncomment the above code to play around with it:
    //return res(2); //This will have no effect
    throw (5); //This is the only exception that can work

Reading: This is what the docs mention about return values from inside the handler function of then():

The behavior of the returned promise (call it p) depends on the handler's execution result, following a specific set of rules. If the handler function returns a value: p gets fulfilled with the returned value as its value.


When I run the snippet it outputs Value2: 1.

You say "the return value from then and catch will be passed to finally", but the finally reference docs say "The function is called with no arguments.". How does it pass the return values then?

Yes, it will return Value2: 1 because .finally() is supposed to be transparent, and does not change the eventual state of the promise. So it will resolve with the value which the promise is suppose to resolve/reject with.

@Kissaki changed my terminologies. By passing i meant only in technical terms without getting into what happens internally. thanks

The finally() function return value is ignored unless it is a rejected promise:

A function to asynchronously execute when this promise becomes settled. Its return value is ignored unless the returned value is a rejected promise. The function is called with no arguments.

finally() returns a promise that

on error or reject will reject
otherwise settles on the called-on promise state


If onFinally throws an error or returns a rejected promise, the new promise will reject with that value. Otherwise, the new promise will settle with the same state as the current promise.

Instead of calling the "next" operation within the finally function, call it as a followup in a then on the finally-returned Promise:


function res(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { resolve(v); }) }
function rej(v) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(v); }) }

rej(1)
.then((val) => {
    console.log(`Value1: ${val}`);
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.error(`Caught 1: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 1");
})
.then(() => {
    return res(2)
})  
.then((v) => {
    console.log(`Value2: ${v}`);
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(`Caught 2: ${e}`);
})
.finally(() => {
    console.log("Finally 2");
});



That will result in the output:
Caught 1: 1
Finally 1
Value2: 2
Finally 2


Please kindly help me understand how to correctly chain multiple promise calls without stacking them inside multiple .finally() block levels.  I want to sequentially execute a series of promises, handling the reject() of each promise in turn, but continuing to the next one even if the previous promise rejects.

When I use a .then() after a .finally(), it seems to work, as in here: https://jsfiddle.net/3osawpn4/  Please explain if this is wrong and if so, what is the correct way?

Yes, that is correct. I will edit my answer to use that approach as it is cleaner and more in the spirit of/similar to the question. Relevant is the return value of finally and that then applies in either success or reject cases, which it does.
